# date.php shows only three posts' title. how to fix it?

Tags: archives, date

my `archive.php`

```
<?php wp_get_archives( array( 'type' => 'monthly', 'limit' => 12, 'show_post_count' => 1 ) ); ?><br/>
```

my `date.php`

```
<?php get_header(); 
            while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
            echo the_title() . '<br/><br/>';
            endwhile;
            wp_reset_query();
get_footer();?>
```

when I click **december 2013** form **myblog.com/archive** then it's goes to **myblog.com/2013/12** and showing **only three posts' title** from the december 2013.

how can I fix it to show all the post from the particular month?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) action to modify number of posts per page on date archives. This would go in your theme's `functions.php` file:

```
function wpa_date_posts_per_page( $query ) {
    if ( !is_admin()
        && $query->is_date()
        && $query->is_main_query() ) {
            $query->set( 'posts_per_page', -1 );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpa_date_posts_per_page' );
```

Comment: thanks a lot @milo You saved me again. it's working like a charm. could you bit explain the code please?